# Jersey @FormDataParam("file") FormDataBodyPart with postman

Tags: jersey, postman

Is there any way to test jersey @FormDataParam("file") FormDataBodyPart with postman.

I tried to hit below endpoint with postman

```
@POST
@Path("data/uploadPhoto")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadPhoto(@FormDataParam("file") FormDataBodyPart body) {
```

But postman is not reaching this endpoint

Comment: Use form-data in postman.